# check for duplicates across a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the code below to look for rows that have the same value across a dataframe.
However, it should not be run if the dataframe contains only 1 column of data.
Using it on only 1 column of data blanks out the dataframe because everything is unique.
I have been trying to include an if statement that first checks the column count. But I run into the error below.

```
#Dataframe with only 1 column of data     
final_table <- as.data.frame(c("a","b","c","d","e"))

#Remove rows where all values are the same if dataframe ncol >1.
final_table <- final_table %>% 
  if(ncol(final_table) > 1)  
     {filter(apply(., 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1))}

#Error in if (.) ncol(final_table) > 1 else { : argument is not interpretable as logical
df1 <- data.frame("x1" = c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                  "x2" = c("c","b","c","x","e"),
                  "x3" = c("a","b","t","s","e"))

df1 %>%
   filter(apply(., 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1 ))

#df1  before when run on multiple columns

  x1 x2 x3
1  a  c  a
2  b  b  b
3  c  c  t
4  d  x  s
5  e  e  e

#after when run on multiple columns (correct results)
  x1 x2 x3
1  a  c  a
2  c  c  t
3  d  x  s

#before if run on df with 1 column
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
#after if run on df with 1 column (results not correct)
#I need to insert a conditional statement that checks if ncol > 1
#If ncol == 1 then I don't want to run the function

NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up approach for your logic -

```
rm_dup_col <- function(df) {
  if(ncol(df) > 1) {
    return(
      df[apply(df, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1), ]
    )
  }
  return(df)
}

df1 %>%
  rm_dup_col()

  x1 x2 x3
1  a  c  a
2  c  c  t
3  d  x  s

final_table %>%
  rm_dup_col()

  A
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is find and remove rows where all values are the same.  Distinct and duplicated both do check for duplicated rows.  If I have three columns and in the 3rd row all values were equal to "A" then I want to remove that column.  The function I had above does the job, but what i'm trying to do is drop it into a dplyr chain that has a conditional statement in it that will only run the function if the dataframe has more than 1 column.

Comment: I've updated the original statement above to see if it clarifies the question better.

Comment: Thanks Shree, that took care of it.  Sorry for not being clear earlier.

Comment: No worries. Just check the latest update. You don't need to use `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(ncol(final_table) > 1) {final_table <- final_table %>% filter(apply(., 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1))}
```